# Null vs Marker Interface

Tags: java, marker-interfaces

Can anyone elaborate that what is the core difference between Null interface and Marker interface in Java. I have been asked this question in one of the interview.

Thanks.

Comment: What's a `Null interface`? I only know about `Void`, is that a Null interface by your definition?

Comment: What is the use of marker interface ?  when we should go for marker or null interface? Can any one explain ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Null interface** is just another name for **Marker Interface** or the other way round. They are used interchangeably as far as I know.

These are just interface with no methods in them. Examples of marker interfaces are : `Serializable`, `Cloneable`.

Comment: What is the use of marker interface ?  when we should go for marker or null interface? Can any one explain ?

Comment: @Ved It marks classes. For example, a class that implements `Serializable` is marked as a class with objects that can be serialized.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Ok, Got it

Answer (score 3):

Null interface is another name for marker interface. Such an interface is empty, i.e. without any method declarations.

For example Serializable, Cloneable class in java. In earlier versions of Java, Marker Interfaces were the only way to declare metadata about a class

Comment: In current Java, you would probably use annotations instead.

Answer (score 1):

The null interfaces are marker interfaces, they do not have function declarations in them, they are empty interfaces, this is to convey the compiler that they have to be treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

Null interface is the example of marker interface.

Interface are different types. that are mainly extend interface, markble interface and marker interface.

Difference of marker Inteface and others are that marker interfaces has no methods..Example are;- serilizable-- for serialization. remote -- for remote method communication. your remote interface must extends this marker interface. when your remote interface extends marker interface then it is called as extend interface.

They just tell the compiler that the objects of this class need to be treated differently. some marker interfaces are : Serializable, Remote, Cloneable

Code:

```
interface markerImp 
{


}

class MarkerTest implements markerImp
{

}

public class TestInstanceOf 
{

public static void main(String []args)
{
    MarkerTest mt = new MarkerTest();
    if(mt instanceof markerImp)
{
    System.out.println("True");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("False");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Null interface and Marker interface are same. Both means the empty interface. Marker or Null interface has no methods and by implementing that interface objects will get some ability. For an example, by implementing Serialisable interface our object can be saved to the file and can travel across the network.